# What are the main components, technologies, and features of the next generation of web applications?

Tags: web-development

What's next in the web industry, as social media reaches a plateau, what are the next milestones in this "experiment"?

I guess I'm looking for in depth opinions on what's next in our beloved industry? What's beyond facebook, wikis, collaboration, shiny buttons, and interactive instantaneous communications?

What will drive the next dot com boom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kevin Kelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Kelly_%28editor%29) gave a tedtalk on the subject, titled "[Predicting the next 5,000 days of the web](http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/eng/kevin_kelly_on_the_next_5_000_days_of_the_web.html)." He has some interesting theories.

(The projections start about eight minutes into the video.)

Comment: +1 because you mention TED talk, but -0.000000001 because I think prediction is impossible, but +0.000000001 because I think prediction is fun ;)

Answer (score 4):

Web 3.0 is just made up term like web 2.0 that means nothing. Just throw around a few cliches like HTML5, Cloud computing and you will be there.

Comment: I changed my question to reflect that, I honestly, meant what will the next generation of websites/web apps be like

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript**

Now that modern browsers are becoming much faster and are supporting native implementations of video, audio and canvas, JavaScript is going to continue to explode in popularity.